# Pre-build a docker container, so you can use it in multiple instances without having to wait for the build each time

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having memory issues on my machine because I need to run many instances of a heavy container.

I was wondering is it possible to pre-build a container, and inject it into other containers on different ports, as needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can. In fact that's how Docker images are meant to be distributed.

After you build and tag the image, use [`docker push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) to push to a remote registry. You can then download the image from that registry.

There are many options for private registries, the best-known being:

- [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry)
- [Nexus](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/private-registry-for-docker)
- [AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)

Or if you don't mind your image being public, just push to the [official Docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry).

Comment: DockerHub can also host private repos